# Reset Graphics in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

Following Code Draws a structure of a molecule. If I don't pass a molecule the last structure continue to show up in the JPanel. How do I reset this to a blank canvas when there is no molecule. In other words what should I put inside else{} of drawMolecule() method?

Comment: I doubt it is related to your problem but you have a typo in super.paintComponents(g). Get rid of the "s", it should be super.paintComponent(g);

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new BufferedImage in the else or you could get the BufferedImage's Graphics2D component, set its background color via `setBackground(Color c)` and then clear the image via `clearRect(...)` then dispose of the Graphics2D object when done via its `dispose()` method.

In fact, on review of your code I don't see you doing this. Don't forget to dispose of the Graphics or Graphics2D resource when done using them, if you've created them yourself (not if obtained from the JVM say via its paint or paintComponent method).

Comment: I tried both dispose() and clearRect().. Did not work! I also tried moving  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); out of the second if block.. nothing!

Comment: @lochi: "did not work" tells us little. Show your new code and any error messages or information on misbehaviors as an edit to your original post and then please flag me back.